# GRUB unable to install. Installation fail

Tags: grub2

While installing ubuntu 12.04 from http://www.ubuntu.com/ mention site .after selecting packages i am facing GRUB installation fail and cannot be boot.

Comment: which method are you following to do the install? wubi?

Comment: Quick question. Does your mother board have EFI instead of a regular bios? If this is the case, you need to add a EFI partition. I struggled with this for a while, but it only requires a partition about 10mb in size (though use at least 100 to be safe).

Comment: Info about System Specification will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)'s "Recommended repair". It will reinstall GRUB and provide a BootInfo URL in case you still have boot problems.

Comment: The grub-pc package failed to install into /traget/. without the GRUB boot loader ,the installed system will not boot.  i am get this problem .

Comment: 8 gb ram ; 160 HD ; i7 processer ; trying to install ubuntu 12.04 (64) bit . this is configuration i am trying.